# Adding custom macros to completion list with AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex, auto-completion

I would like AUCTeX (that is, Emacs with auctex loaded) to suggest more LaTeX macros when using completion (<kbd>M-Tab</kbd> or <kbd>C-Ret</kbd>) than it does by default.
I would like to have macros from packages I have downloaded on CTAN and macros I have written.
I would also like it if it would complete `\section` or other macros that can be accessed via <kbd>C-c C-s</kbd>, <kbd>C-c C-e</kbd> etc.

Solution:
I could not make the code quoted by [AUCTeX wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AUCTeX#toc18)
work. i get an error on loading emacs but did not looked much further in because I ca bear the nuisance of appending a few lines to my files.

The link given by Ben ([Automatic add of private macros](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Automatic-Private.html) contains a working solution, thus I accept his answer. I had come across this page in my researchs but somehow messed up things. What eventually worked for me was using `TeX-auto-generate TEX AUTO` to create a bunch of .el files in the ~/.emacs.d/auctex/auto direcoty. Note that this directory must be created *beforhand*.
For some reasons `TeX-macro-private` did not achieve the wanted result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AUCTeX has to be configured to parse files so that it can extract the macros you want.  Make sure you have the variable `TeX-parse-self` set to `t`, so that it scans the current file for macros defined there, set `TeX-auto-regexp-list` to `TeX-auto-full-regexp-list` so it looks for as many macros as it can, and `TeX-auto-parse-length` to `999999` so it handles long files.  These can be set in your `.emacs` file, and overridden as needed as file-local variables in your individual projects if they give you trouble.  You should also try adding

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% TeX-master: "your-main-filename"
%%% End:
```

to the bottom of all files belonging to your project, so that AUCTeX knows how to get back from one included file to the main one, and then to the other included files.

With all that done, it should be finding pretty much all the macros in your project.

**EDIT**

According to the [AUCTeX wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AUCTeX#toc18), you can avoid the `TeX-master` local variable by asking AUCTeX to guess the master file; they post the necessary elisp code to do this.

To check additional directories worth of style files, add the directories to the `TeX-macro-private` lists (see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Automatic-Private.html)).

Comment: It woks for the macros defined inside the document. That's already something, but I would like auctex to know about macros defined in .sty files stored in my local latex files directories. I reckon it has something to do with TeX-macro-global or the likes but  I don't know what.I'll clarify my question.

Comment: @AlfredM., presumably these are .sty files that you're including via `usepackage` or `include`?  If you are, and it's not working, then I'm surprised.  If you aren't, then I'm not, since there would be no way for AUCTeX to know that those files are relevant to your document :)

Comment: It is. Sometimes I have nested usepackage but that should not pose any problem, right?

Comment: When the .sty files are in the directory of the .tex files, it wokrks all right.
I reckon I have to add the path to my .sty files directory somewhere.