# Access from included files to environments in AUCtex

Tags: emacs, auctex

When I am writing slides, I usually use one master file and several dependent files; as a macro package I use `beamer`. I would like to access the environments defined by the beamer package also in the dependent files (which I include through `\input`) through `C-c C-e`. I can access them in the master file. By the same token, I would like to access the macros in my macro packages, which I also include through `\input`. My .emacs file contains the lines

```lisp
(setq-default TeX-master nil)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Does setting the variable `LaTeX-default-style` to `beamer` help, e.g. putting (setq LaTeX-default-style beamer)` in your emacs or by putting `-*- mode: LaTeX; LaTeX-default-style: beamer; -*-` in the first line of the dependent files?

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47416/3731) might point you in the right direction.

The summary of it is that the `\input` files can be configured to find their master file by appending the following lines at the end:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% TeX-master: "your-main-filename"
%%% End:
```

By doing this, and with AUCTeX's ability to parse the files for macros, it should be able to recognize that the input files belong to a master `beamer` file, and use the beamer environments.